# CSS header scroll with navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to have my Header to float above my `navbar` as the user is scrolling down. I tried using `top: 0;` but that just gave me this:

[image]

I have my CSS below

```css
        .header {
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #1abc9c;
            color: white;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 0;

        }

        .header h1 {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 0;
        }

        .navbar a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }



        .navbar a.right {
            float: right;


        }


        .navbar a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: pink;
        }


        .navbar a.active {
            background-color: #666;
            color: white;

        }
```

Also Some HTML:

```
        <div class="header">
        <button type="button" class="button" onclick="Iknownothing()">Click Me!</button>
            <h3>Title</h3>

        </div>
```

Comment: add a `padding-top: yourHeaderHeight` to the content element.

Comment: Please can you add your html to the question too - see [mcve]

Comment: try display:block; on your header

Comment: @Pete done adding HTML

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to add padding-top to your header text element

```
.header {
        padding-top:*amount of padding you want maybe in percent or px or rem*;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1abc9c;
        color: white;
        position: sticky;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        top: 0;

    }
```